# How to pass ConnectionString when deploying AzureRM Web App in TFS?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-web-app-service, ms-release-management

I am struggling to pass ConnectionString when deploying AzureRM Web App in TFS Release Manager. I have tried to put the ConnectionString in the "Additional Arguments" field and provided the correct variables from the "Variables" section. However, I am getting the following error:

[image]

`[error] Error: Unrecognized argument '-connectionString'. Error count: 1.`

Does someone have experience in how to set up ConnectionString when working with AzureRM Endpoint to deploy Web Apps? As far as I know, the approach described above works fine when using Azure Web App Deployment with Azure Classic Endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to use some 3-party extension such as [Azure WebApp Configuration](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pascalnaber.PascalNaber-Xpirit-WebAppConfiguration#overview) task.

This task reads VSTS/TFS variables and adds those as AppSettings and ConnectionStrings to an Azure WebApp.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could inculcate the following sample, to fit your deployment via TFS.

```
{
      "apiVersion": "2014-11-01",
      "name": "appsettings",
      "type": "config",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('siteName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "AppSettingKey1": "Some value",
        "AppSettingKey2": "My second setting",
        "AppSettingKey3": "My third setting"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2014-11-01",
      "name": "connectionstrings",
      "type": "config",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('siteName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "ConnString1": { "value": "My custom connection string", "type": "custom" },
        "ConnString2": { "value": "My SQL connection string", "type": "SQLAzure" }
      }
    },
```

Refer the sample [here](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/df4100cde76fc1f2f714cf2021b48f902e33040f/ARMTemplates/WebAppManyFeatures.json#L96-L120) for more details